# How to move a single file between directories in the Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to stick with using the Google Cloud Shell commands to deploy a simple Flask application, and I'm running into issues with the simplest things. When I upload a python file it's automatically uploaded to the home directory, and for the life of me I can't figure out a way to move it to where I need.

I tried using gsutil mv but with no luck. I can move an entire directory but I just want to move a .py file from one place to another, this should not be so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Shell is actually running `bash` under a Linux OS, so you want to use [bash](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse391/17sp/bash.html) and/or [Linux](https://ss64.com/bash/) commands.

Here's an example of actually moving the `blah.txt` file (using [the `mv` command](https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html)) from the `some_user`'s home directory to its `test_mv` subdirectory in the cloud shell:

```
some_user@cloudshell:~ (my_project)$ date > blah.txt
some_user@cloudshell:~ (my_project)$ ls -la blah.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 some_user some_user 29 Jun 13 23:00 blah.txt
some_user@cloudshell:~ (my_project)$ mkdir test_mv
some_user@cloudshell:~ (my_project)$ mv blah.txt test_mv/
some_user@cloudshell:~ (my_project)$ ls -la blah.txt
ls: cannot access 'blah.txt': No such file or directory
some_user@cloudshell:~ (my_project)$ ls -la test_mv/blah.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 some_user some_user 29 Jun 13 23:00 test_mv/blah.txt
```